# How does the following code work?

Tags: c++, templates, v8

```
    #define TYPE_CHECK(T, S)                                     \
    while (false) {                                              \
      *(static_cast<T* volatile*>(0)) = static_cast<S*>(0);      \
    }
```

I am reading Google [v8](http://code.google.com/p/v8/source/browse/trunk/include/v8.h)'s code and found the above macro for type check.

However, I do not understand why it works. while(false) never get executed, right?
Can someone explain those lines?
Thanks

Comment: It is a compile time check of two types which assignes the content of one null pointer to another. The compiler would detect incompatibility of types (and stop compilation). The code would **NOT** be executed (thanks to) due to the false value in the condition.

Comment: Really neat.. this is going to my trunk right now!

Comment: is there any reason to use 'while' instead of 'if'?

Comment: `while` is used since `if` would allow `else` afterwards, which might happen accidentially ...

Comment: if cannot be used because of its paring with nearest else. With if you could not do e.g. if (xxx) TYPE_CHECK(T,S) else SOMETHING_ELSE(T,S)

Comment: IMO it's ugly. Better use a real function template for this and don't pollute the global name space. Using textual replacement has drawbacks and hidden pitfalls. Consider how you cannot do `TYPE_CHECK(int[1], int[1]);`. Previously I thought that it would fail with `TYPE_CHECK(::type, foo)` (producing the alternative token <:), but I'm wrong. `static_cast<T>`, when expanding `T`, doesn't produce such an alternative token out of the `<` and the start of expanded `T`. I don't like nor know macros, obviously :)

Comment: I think we should rename this question to be able to search for it. Something like "static_cast in while(false)". Any objections?

Comment: why assignment is not removed by the compiler due to the optimization ? `while (false)` can be detected as a 'will never execute'

Comment: @cprogrammer: The compiler probably won't emit any code, but it still has to check the source for errors. You can't write `if (false) some_function_that_does_not_exist();` either.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, but the compiler still performs syntax & semantic checks on the loop contents. So if something is wrong (i.e. the implicit type conversion from `S*` to `T*` is illegal, which happens if `T` is neither `S` nor a base class of `S`), compilation fails. Otherwise, the quality of the resulting machine code is not affected since the optimizer will detect the nonreachable code and remove it silently.

Comment: The casts are always legal.  The code is testing for existence of a standard conversion from `S*` to `T*`.  (`T` may be a base class of `S`.)

Answer (score 12):

Quite a fancy hack - the purpose of the macro seems to be to check if the type `S` is assignable to (i.e., is a subclass of) the type `T`. If it is not, the pointer cast from `S*` to `T*` will produce a compiler error. The `while (false)` prevents the code from actually having any other effect.