# How to understand this piece of C++ code, which is for type checking？

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does the following code work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5237163/how-does-the-following-code-work)

```
#define TYPE_CHECK(T, S)                                       \
  while (false) {                                              \
    *(static_cast<T* volatile*>(0)) = static_cast<S*>(0);      \
  }
```

I found it tricky, how does it work? And why volatile?

Comment: @iammilind: it won't be executed, only compiled, that's the whole point

Answer (score 4):

Since it's a static cast, it's getting the compiler to ensure that the pointers to the two types are equivalent. The `while(false)` ensures it's never run and that it's only a compile time thing.

Comment: Ah, nice! +1. I would never thing about such thing.

Comment: It would be nice if you could explain how exactly the code works. Especially what effect making the pointer volatile has.

Comment: I always have to remember rinterpret_cast => runtime

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5237163/how-does-the-following-code-work

Answer (score 1):

It statically checks that a `S*` can be cast into a `T*`. No code is executed at runtime. I think the `volatile` prevents optimization, which would just make the compiler ignore the code.

Comment: Optimization would not permit the compiler to ignore the code entirely, since the compiler still has to diagnose invalid code whether it's optimized away or not. I suspect the `volatile` is there to suppress a warning from some compiler that notices a null pointer is dereferenced. Well, it isn't since the expression isn't evaluated, but the expression says to do it. If I'm right, then `volatile` indicates "user appears to think he knows what he's doing, and really wants to dereference that null pointer, so don't warn".

Answer (score 0):

The code is checking if S* can be assigned to T*, and forcing a compile error if it cannot. As for volatile I'm not sure.

Answer (score -1):

If the types can't be casted, it won't compile. But it is never executed.