# static_cast<T* volatile*> - what does this code mean?

Tags: c++

In V8.h of Google V8 Javascript engine, there is a piece of code to check if two types match at compiling stage. I can understand large part of it, but can't comprehend the syntax of `static_cast<T* volatile*>`, what does it mean by adding unusual **volatile*** and why is it needed?

```
#define TYPE_CHECK(T, S)                                       \
  while (false) {                                              \
    *(static_cast<T* volatile*>(0)) = static_cast<S*>(0);      \
  }
```

I noted same code has been discussed in this topic below, but not in detail of the question I am asking.
[How does the following code work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5237163/how-does-the-following-code-work)

Comment: `volatile*` means pointer-to-`volatile`. Are you asking what `volatile` means?

Comment: @zenith the question is why `volatile` appears in this code at all (i.e. why would the code break or perform differently if it were removed)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`T* volatile*` means "pointer to `volatile` pointer to `T`". So it is the same as `T**`, except that when dereferenced, the resulting lvalue is `volatile`.

As for why `volatile` is needed here, that's explained in the commit description, which you can view here: https://github.com/v8/v8/commit/35a80e16241308b4f476875d0f96282cf697a029

> TYPE_CHECK in v8.h should assign to volatile qualified null-pointer.
>
> Unless the pointer is volatile qualified, Clang will warn that LLVM
> removes the assignment during optimization. This is not a problem as
> that code should never execute, but the warning is treated as an error
> when building Chromium, and thus stops the build.

Comment: @M.M because then the code would actually get executed once

Comment: very good answer. Just one more question what's the different between *(static_cast<T**>(0)) = static_cast<S*>(0) and (static_cast<T*>(0)) = static_cast<S*>(0);

Comment: @RicoWang Please add a separate question.